# Flask: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'drivername' when querying a table from Python terminal

Tags: python, sqlite, flask

EDIT: I added the following lines to config.py:

```
print(type(SECRET_KEY), SECRET_KEY)
print(type(SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI), SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI)
print(SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI == "sqlite:///site.db")
```

And then when I start the flask app with **python run.py**, I get the output

```
<class 'str'> secret
<class 'str'> sqlite:///site.db
True
```

Now in the python terminal when I run the following command

```
>>> from main import create_app, db
```

I'm getting output

```
<class 'NoneType'> None
<class 'NoneType'> None
False
```

So it seems like the values are not getting loaded from the .env file. Am I missing any imports? Because if hardcode the value of the SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI to sqlite:///site.db the output becomes:

```
<class 'NoneType'> None
<class 'str'> sqlite:///site.db
True
```

---

I'm working on a Flask application and I restructured it using Blueprints. After this change when I try to interact with tables in my database the following error gets thrown:

```
'NoneType' object has no attribute 'drivername'
```

I'm loading any secret values or database URI's from a .env file using the dotenv package. In fact, in the front end the application is working because when I make changes they are saved and being rendered on the page. However, I want to work with tables through the table to create dummy data quickly, but for some reason I'm not.

#### __ *init* __.py

This file is part of the main package called **main**

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_bcrypt import Bcrypt
from flask_login import LoginManager
from main.config import Config

db = SQLAlchemy()
bcrypt = Bcrypt()
login = LoginManager()
login.login_view = 'users.login'


def create_app(config_class=Config):
    # Create app and setup config
    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.config.from_object(Config)

    # Link extensions to the app
    db.init_app(app)
    bcrypt.init_app(app)
    login.init_app(app)

    # Add route imports
    from main.users.routes import users
    from main.decks.routes import decks
    from main.cards.routes import cards
    from main.errors.handlers import errors

    # Register blueprints
    app.register_blueprint(users)
    app.register_blueprint(decks)
    app.register_blueprint(cards)
    app.register_blueprint(errors)

    return app
```

### config.py

```
from dotenv import load_dotenv
import os
load_dotenv()

class Config():
    SECRET_KEY = os.getenv('SECRET_KEY')
    SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = os.getenv('SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI')
```

### .env

```
SECRET_KEY="secret"
SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI="sqlite:///site.db"
```

This is how I'm trying to interact with tables from the python terminal

```
>> from main import db, create_app
>> from main.models import Card
>> app = create_app()
>> with app.app_context():
        Card.query.first()
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'drivername'
```

Comment: maybe don't use "secret" as the key that gives access to your application?

Comment: @monsieuralfonse64 yeah I'm not its some random generated string but I just changed it to secret to be succinct.

Answer (score 0):

This is quite a generic error, because all it means is that somewhere along the line you have an object with type `NoneType`, and `None` has no attributes as far as I know, so it will raise an `AttributeError`. Looking at the question context, I think the most likely error is referring to a database query that is returning `None`.

So look for a point in your code when you do something like this:

```
x = Card.query.get(65) # let's say there are only 52 cards, so this is None
return x.drivername
```

This will cause an `AttributeError` and has clearly crashed your code. So it will be in any file that is imported by the `create_app`, and any files they import themselves (if this is quite a lot, think about where you use database queries the most).

Comment: Querying in my routes works fine. For example, when I create a new user I will create query the database to check if an existing user has used that same email, and I'm not running into any errors then. I'm trying to manipulate my database/tables through the Python terminal and that's where I'm having an issue.

Comment: @aDabOfRanch okay, but **you** aren't providing the `AttributeError` when you run it in the terminal – it's an issue with your code. Either that or you've set up your shell context oddly.

Comment: It's the same errors I posted: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'drivername' when I run in the terminal. Check out my edits at the top. Honestly I think I'm missing some import because it runs fine if I hard code the values from the .env file.

Comment: @aDabOfRanch perhaps your `load_dotenv()` isn't working – don't you need to put your file path into it? Like: `load_dotenv("path/to/file/.env")`

Answer (score 0):

Yeah all I had to do in the python terminal was the load the .env file using the load_dotenv() and find_dotenv() functions. In essence, before you call create_app you need to load your environment variables in, which I wasn't entering as a command in my Python terminal, but was automatically getting ran in my script.